# Find the higher order expansion for det(I+ϵA) where ϵ is small

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

For small $\epsilon$ I want to prove 
\begin{align}
\det(I+\epsilon A) = 1 + \epsilon tr(A) + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2} \left((tr(A))^2 - tr(A^2) \right) + O(\epsilon^3)
\end{align}
Furthermore I want to know how to calculate higher order terms in general.

For the linear order I found one in [Find the expansion for $\det(I+\epsilon A)$ where $\epsilon$ is small without using eigenvalue.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836046/find-the-expansion-for-deti-epsilon-a-where-epsilon-is-small-without-us)

How about in general high order terms?

Comment: $\log(det(B)) = Tr(\log(B))$ should be enough to get you going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\frac12\left(\operatorname{tr}^2(A)-\operatorname{tr}(A^2)\right)
=\frac12\left[(\sum_i\lambda_i)^2-\sum_i\lambda_i^2\right]=\sum_{i_1<i_2}\lambda_{i_1}\lambda_{i_2}$ and
\begin{aligned}
&\det(I+\epsilon A)=\prod_{i=1}^n(1+\epsilon\lambda_i)\\
&=1
+\epsilon\operatorname{tr}(A)
+\epsilon^2\left(\sum_{i_1<i_2}\lambda_{i_1}\lambda_{i_2}\right)
+\cdots
+\epsilon^{n-1}\left(\sum_{i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_{n-1}}\lambda_{i_1}\lambda_{i_2}\cdots\lambda_{i_{n-1}}\right)
+\epsilon^n\det(A),
\end{aligned}
the result follows. In theory, one may write the coefficients $\sum_{i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k}\lambda_{i_1}\lambda_{i_2}\cdots\lambda_{i_k}$ in terms of the traces of the powers of $A$ by using [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), but for higher-order terms, such trace expressions can be quite complicated.

Answer (score 0):

From @user721481

Note that 
\begin{align}
&log(det(I+\epsilon A)) = tr(log(I+\epsilon A)) = tr(\epsilon A - \frac{\epsilon^2 A^2}{2} + \cdots ) \\
&det(I+\epsilon A) = e^{tr(log(I+\epsilon A))} = 1 + \epsilon tr(A) + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2} \left((tr(A))^2 - tr(A^2) \right) + O(\epsilon^3)
\end{align}
In the process I used taylor expansion of $e^x$ and $log(1+x)$.